# ¿Cómo generar un exe de una carpeta html donde hay un proyecto web?

Tags: html, windows

¿Cómo puedo generar un `exe` para `windows` a partir de una web o bien desde una `url` (www.unaweb.com) o bien desde una carpeta con una web `html` dentro. Lo hago con `mac`, pero en `windows` no sé cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Mirate el IntelXDK.

Comment: Esa es una buena opción pero deberías saber que el IntelXDK esta construido sobre el Apache Cordova

Comment: IntelXDK lo descubrí el año pasado y me gusta bastante pero probé de hacer esto que quiero con el programa y tampoco entiendo que es lo que hace. Me descarga un zip que cuando lo abro están mis archivos html. Y yo quiero un único archivo que al ejectuarlo me abra mi juego, sin ver toda la carpeta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opciones para lo que quieres hay muchas, algunas mejores que las otras por lo que yo te voy a recomendar dos opciones que deben cubrir la mayoría de las necesidades.

La más popular en mi opinión es [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org) porque permite que tu aplicación sea multiplataforma y tiene un enorme repositorio de [plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/) que permite agregar a tu aplicación gran cantidad de funcionalidad que no está disponible para las aplicaciones web tradicionales.

Si este no cubre tus necesidades te recomiendo entonces [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) que es el framework utilizado para crear el IDE de programación [Atom](https://atom.io/) y [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). Puedes comprobar por ti mismo que el look and feel de las aplicaciones creadas es muy similar al de las aplicaciones nativas.

Ambos frameworks son open-source

Si aun quieres más opciones puedes usar [NW.js](http://nwjs.io/) o [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.org/)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, todo lo que comentas lo conozco pero no lo uso. Tenía en mente usar algo más automático con menos trabajo, porque yo tampoco soy un crack usando frameworks. Por eso intelXDK me gusta, porque es un proceso bastante automático. Si nadie me da la respuesta de alguna herramienta que haga de forma super simple lo que quiero, al final usaré alguna de tus opciones. Me tendré que poner las pilas y aprender más de lo que se, pero no dispongo de mucho tiempo para ello.

Comment: @MarcLemien Comentaste que no te gustaba Apache Cordova por eso especifique en un comentario que el IntelXDK esta construido sobre este, por lo que la capacidad de generar .exe de este framework va a depender de las [plataformas soportadas](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/support/index.html) por cordova. Electron en cambio te genera un .exe y puedes [empaquetar](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.8/tutorial/application-distribution) el resto de los archivos en un fichero .asar si no quieres tener ficheros sueltos. No es tan complejo cuando lo hayas logrado por primera vez.

Comment: Hola, otra opción podría ser [App Studio](http://appstudio.windows.com/en-us/home/howto), creo que se puede [generar una App a partir un sitio web](http://windowsapptutorials.com/windows-phone/appstudio/creating-a-windows-phone-app-for-your-website-using-microsoft-app-studio/), la aplicación creo que funcionaría en W8 y W10. Personalmente me atrae más Electron, a ver si lo pruebo algún día. Saludos //cc: @MarcLemien

Answer (score 0):

[Convertir aplicaciones web en ejecutables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29686011/how-do-i-convert-web-application-into-desktop-executable)
Quizás requiera de algunos ajustes en tu aplicación, pero Apache Cordova funciona bastante bien para este propósito.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. En la 1ª opción se habla de cordova, ya no lo uso cordova porque hay muchos agujeros de seguridad. Y además me resulta complicado por lo que yo se hacer. En la 2ª opción la web de este chico web2gap tiene buena pinta, pero me ha creado una app de mac, eso ya sabía hacerlo y la de windows me crea muchísimos archivos menos el exe ejecutable. Espero a ver si alguien me da alguna respuesta más. Gracias por tu tiempo. Te daré un punto cuando tenga suficiente reputación.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres un EXE, un ejecutable, deberás usar un lenguaje que compile en EXE como c# o VB, pedirle al sistema que abra un navegador y cargue la web.
Lo de Apache cordoba y tal sirve para crear paquetes de instalación y subirlos a la tienda (de windows, android i Mac OS) pero NO crea ejecutables EXE.
En visual Basic hacer esto es trivial, 4 lineas.