# Es posible crear una app html.exe?

Tags: javascript, html5

Buenas, tengo en mis manos un proyecto donde realizo una animación conocida como pageflip (efecto pagina para un libro virtual), la situación es que la mayoría de las formas en que se puede realizar no cumple con el producto final el cual dicho sea de paso es un libro virtual que se pueda portar en un  dispositivo flash, es decir una memoria portable.

Mi pregunta: ¿Es posible hacer un ejecutable haciendo uso de las tecnologías html5, css3 y javascript?

Si no fuese posible, que recomendación me podrían brindar?

Comment: Hola Roberto, este no es sitio de recomendaciones ni sugerencias ni opiniones... aqui se hacen preguntas concretas de codigo (ej: "en mi  metodo `pageFlip()` no coge bien el valor ....). Un saludo

Comment: Esta pregunta es un posible duplicado de esta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/9157/cómo-generar-un-exe-de-una-carpeta-html-donde-hay-un-proyecto-web/17207#17207

Comment: Se puede convertir a APP usando aplicaciones como intel XDK, pero genera paquetes de instalación, NO EXE.

Comment: @RobertoGarcia exactamente, que es lo que quieres hacer ?? generar 1 archivo que contenga la aplicación, o que dicha aplicación, formada por múltiples páginas html, sea usable desde un dispositivo, sin necesitar servidor ??

Comment: Disculpen no sabia las reglas del stackoverflow, y @Trauma mi intencion es eso que comentas una aplicacion que se pueda ejecutar desde un dispositivo en mi caso un penthdrive

Comment: @RobertoGarcia una aplicación ? un archivo suelto, que lo contenga todo ? o simplemente una forma de que que tu web se ejecute, aunque sea con todos los archivos ?

Comment: Simplemente una forma que se ejecute desde un penthdrive, el pageflip ya lo tengo, los archivos ya los he creado el objetivo principal ya esta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un Servidor web portable mi preferido el Server2Go. Como su nombre lo indica un Servidor web portable,puede ser instalado y utilizado desde dispositivos tales como tarjetas de memoria, pendrives, CD, DVD o desde un disco duro. Pero su principal punto fuerte es el de poder ser llevado a cualquier sitio y ejecutado desde allí.

**Caracteristicas del server2Go:**

Además de su facilidad de instalación y ser gratuito, Server2Go, soporta PHP 5, MySQL 5, SQLite y Pearl 5.8. Su licencia es donationware, lo que quiere decir que si se dona una cantidad de dinero se podrá acceder a características ampliadas. Su sistema está basado en Apache y está disponible para Windows (98, XP, Vista y 7) y Mac OS. Soporta las versiones posteriores de Internet Explorer 6, Firefox, Safari, Camino y algunos otros navegadores. Detecta automáticamente el nombre del host y el puerto cuando iniciamos el navegador, se apaga automáticamente cuando se cierra el navegador y además soporta PHP 5 con múltiples extensiones instaladas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el dato, lo tomare a consideración :)

Answer (score 1):

Si es posible, justamente lo que necesitas es: [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/). El cual hace uso de las tecnologías que listas html,css y javascript para generar aplicaciones multiplataforma(linux,ios,windows), con esto quiero decirte que podras generar tu ejecutable(.exe). Algunos ejemplos de aplicaciones realizadas en electron son Slack, Atom, GitKraken, Nylas, VS code entre otras.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el dato, que tengas un excelente dia